# Pass data from controller 1 to controller 2 in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, model-view-controller

How to pass data from controller 1 to controller 2 in codeigniter.

I have this scenario.
Controller 1 is using $id which are unique.

```
controller1/view/1
controller1/view/2
controller1/view/3
```

and I need to get those $id and pass it everytime on my controller2. `So in my controller 2, I need to get the $id which is 1,2,3.` I don't want to use session as it's not gonna work and I don't want to use segment also as it's giving error if last parameter is empty. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this on your controller, whenever your last parameter is empty its not giving an error

```
function view($id=NULL){

}
```

Comment: thanks I'll try it. But any solution without using session?